# How to look for datatype rather than page type

Tags: javascript, jquery, umbraco, jquery-isotope

I'm using isotope to filter different content on my webpage. Right now I have a showcase page in umbraco and I have two datatypes called `images` and `videos`

On other pages where I'm using isotope to filter content I am using the page type to do so:

```
$('#filterNews').click(function () {
    $('.isotope').isotope({ filter: '.NewsItem', layoutMode: 'masonry' });
    $('.newsfilters .btn').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

However, what I need is to amend the above so that it looks on the page for the datatypes. I've tried the following:

```
$('#filterNews').click(function () {
    $('.isotope').isotope({ filter: '@CurrentPage.Images', layoutMode: 'masonry' });
    $('.newsfilters .btn').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

And I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: @CurrentPage.Images

I've even tried to get the actual content type from Umbraco as well but that came up with illegal syntax errors.

is there a way I can amend my javascript so it looks for the proper datatype I am after, and not the page type?

Answer (score 0):

The error you get here is due to the fact that @CurrentPage.Images is razor script which the server is trying to run while rendering the page. If the property "Images" on the current page is not defined, this will fail (which is what you see here).

What you are doing here is also not really what you think you are doing. The isotope script is javascript which runs clientside, therefore it does not work with razor serverside-script in the way you are writing it here.

It sounds like the filter in isotope needs a class name to filter on, which means you would have to look at the template code that actually outputs your images and videos. Without seeing your template I can't really tell you which part it is, other than it will most likely be something with a 'foreach' or a 'for' loop, writing out your image and video elements. In this loop you would have to modify it to add a class of 'video' or 'image' to the respective elements being output and then you will be able to use '.video' and '.image' in the filter attribute of isotope.